# How to do one to one relation in python google appengine datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

```
class User(db.Model):
    username = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    password = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    email_address = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    profile_img = db.BlobProperty()

class Book(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name='books')
    #first build
    Book_1 = db.BooleanProperty(default=False) 
    Book_2 = db.BooleanProperty(default=False) 
    Book_3 = db.BooleanProperty(default=False) 
    Book_4 = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
```

Hi I'd like to create a one to one relationship with this two model. Are there anything I can do to make it so that it'll never create more than one Book model for each user?

Thanks.

Comment: If you create the book model with a keyname of "book" and make the ancestor the User, and use get_or_insert then there can never be more than one book for a user.  This means you can also do away with the reference property in Book.  Even with get_or_insert their could be multiple Book entities referencing a user unless you control the key generation explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [get or insert](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert) might be useful for this. Perhaps when you create your user model you can `get_or_insert` the book model with the username (presumably unique) as it's key, obviously creating it that first time and getting it subsequently.

```
Model.get_or_insert (key_name, **kwds)
```

> Attempts to get the entity of the model's kind with the given key
>   name. If it exists, get_or_insert() simply returns it. If it doesn't
>   exist, a new entity with the given kind, name, and parameters in kwds
>   is created, stored, and returned.
>
> The get and subsequent (possible) put operations are wrapped in a
>   transaction to ensure atomicity. Ths means that get_or_insert() will
>   never overwrite an existing entity, and will insert a new entity if
>   and only if no entity with the given kind and name exists.